# How to set branch format in gitconfig (not an alias)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-config

I have this alias `git config --global alias.recent 'branch --sort=-committerdate --format="%(committerdate:relative)%09%(refname:short)"'`, it works fine: `git recent`

but I want to make this default behaviour when doing `git branch` using a **gitconfig file**. I can't get the `format` piece working:

```
[branch]
  # this works
  sort = -committerdate
  
  # doesn't work:
  format = \"%(committerdate:relative)%09%(refname:short)\"
  # neither:
  format = "%(committerdate:relative)%09%(refname:short)"

[alias]
  # this is what git config command above adds:
  recent = branch --sort=-committerdate --format=\"%(committerdate:relative)%09%(refname:short)\"
```

When I do `git branch` just the sorting works. How can I get the `format` working as well?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what made you expect `format = ...` to work here?

Answer (score 2):

Not every command line option has its config counterpart. `git branch` has a lot of [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#_options) but `git config branch.` has [only few](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupMerge).